# Cannot set readonly property: level for class: org.gradle.internal.logging.services.DefaultLoggingManager in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle task as follows which is throwing the below error while running:

```
Cannot set readonly property: level for class: org.gradle.internal.logging.services.DefaultLoggingManager

task swaggerGenerator(type: JavaExec) {
    doFirst {
        mkdir "$buildDir/api"
    }
    main = "xyz"
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    logging.level = "ERROR"
}
```

Gradle version being used is 7.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `logging.level` line from the gradle task to get rid of this error.